# How to write "a implies b or c" in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How would I write the following in Prolog?

```
a -> b V c
```

In English that would be `a implies that b or c (or both)`

Comment: Am I using the wrong term? The answers seem to say that imply is not the correct term. Aren't all (most) prolog clauses read as something implies something else (`something_else:-something.`)? I am not learning Prolog in English, so I may be using the wrong term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clause

```
a => (b ; c)     % ';' means 'or'
```

is not a Horn clause and hence **cannot be represented** in (pure) Prolog (see e.g [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Rules_and_facts)). On the other hand `(b ; c) => a` is a Horn clause and can obviously be represented by two Prolog rules.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `;`. Can you explain what it is, and what those two clauses mean?

Comment: I used `;` to represent 'or' (= disjunction), i.e. your `v` symbol. I chose it because it is a predefined 'or' operator in many Prolog interpreters. So, you can write `a :- b;c.` meaning `(b or c) imply a`. You cannot express `a implies (b or c)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do with with this implies statement. But I would have thought the following would suffice (bear in mind this is SICStus not swi, but at this low level I think it's all the same).

```
predicate(a, b).
predicate(a, c).

?- predicate(a, Then).
Then = b ;
Then = c ;
no

?- predicate(x, Then).
no
```

You could do more complicated checks to make sure a is never an unbound value (to prevent `predicate(If, b)`. being true), but unless you're making a huge application then I'm sure good documentation would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, "b or c" is the same thing as "b or c (or both)"

You can read about logical operators in Prolog here: http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/Prolog.html

Can you explain a bit more please what you're trying to do with 'implies'?

Comment: I mean like `a:-b,c.` means `b and c implies a`, but the other way. Unofficially, that would be `b,c:-a.`

Comment: If After that I ask `?-b.` or `?-c.` I should get false or unkown or somesuch, but if I also have `d:-b. d:-c.` then `?-d.` should be true.

Comment: You can just write two clauses
    b :- a.
    c :- a.